# Install a second hard drive and extend first hard drive partition across it?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk

I have a laptop running Ubuntu linux, it has one NVME hard drive with 1TB space on it. (this drive has boot encryption enabled)

I have purchased a second NVME drive with 2TB space on it. Is there I way I can install the second hard drive and have the OS treat them as one 3TB hard drive?
Without moving all my data on/off or losing any data?

edit:

It seems the first hard drive has LVM?

```
sudo lvscan
[sudo] password for work: 
  ACTIVE            '/dev/data/root' [<945.36 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Do you have LVM enabled? With logical volumes you could spread your volume group across both disks with `vgextend`.

Comment: @eblock I think so? see updated question. Thanks

Comment: If that's the case and my first HDD is encrypted, would I need to do anything special to setup the second HDD before hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with LVM, but not with the physical drives. Assuming you elected to use LVM in your partitioning when you installed Ubuntu, you simply need to create an LVM PV (Physical Volume) on the new device (usually something similar to a `pvcreate /dev/sdb1` command), then add the new PV to an existing Volume Group (VG) (usually done with some form of `vgextend`).

If you did not use LVM when installing Ubuntu, it will be difficult to impossible to achieve what you want. You can still mount the new disk as a new filesystem without needing to move data, but they will be two distinct filesystems.